# Как рисовать “толстые” полигоны в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Требуется из двумерных полигонов сделать трехмерные полигоны. Как добиться эффекта толщины? Есть идеи на этот счёт?

Comment: Расскажите поподробнее, как вы это себе представляете?

Comment: Представьте себе ровный круг. Если в значительной мере увеличить его толщину получится хороший цилиндр. Из квадрата также можно получить куб. Только пока не представляю, как это всё можно сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку для каждого треугольника в `mesh'e` у вас известна нормаль этого треугольника *(сумма трех вертексных нормалей / 3),* то достаточно просто применить [**экструзию**](http://jmonkeyengine.org/groups/general-2/forum/topic/extrusion-algorithm/) к этому самому треугольнику.

**Что хорошо и удобно** в применении экструзии - то, что результат ее применения к некоторой модели равен комбинации результатов, полученных для всех треугольников в отдельности. **Что плохо** - то, что в случае больших параметров `displacement'а` полученные фрагменты начинают пересекаться и залезать друг на друга, и *необходимо уметь объединять и находить такие пересечения.*

---

В некоторых случаях для получения желаемого результата достаточно просто применить некоторый маппинг, типа [`displacement mapping,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping) но, разумеется, *техники подобного рода применимы далеко не всегда.*

Comment: Хотелось бы получить больше информации по этим технологиям. Также меня интересует вопрос, как будут действовать текстуры на утолщенные полигоны. И возможно ли получить неравномерное утолщение поверхности – превратить, по сути, полигон в некий террейн. Насколько эффективной будет подобная технология?

Answer (score 1):

> Из квадрата также можно получить куб.

Почему не нарисовать просто этот самый куб или цилиндр?

Никаких "утолщенных" полигонов не бывает. Метод предложенный [[@Котик_хочет_кушать](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) в любом случае состоит предполагает создание новых полигонов, с основанием в исходном.

Для террейнов как правило используются карты высот и регулярные сетки полигонов. Т.е. представьте, что у вас есть сетка с квадратными ячейками и каждая точка пересечения линий может находиться на своей высоте. Информация о высотах в таких случаях хранится в виде карты высот: координаты точек на карте соответствуют индексам вершин вашей поверхности, а интенсивность цвета, обозначает высоту.

Можно слегка добиться этого эффекта, используя карты нормалей и бамп-мэппинг, но это годится только для небольших шероховатостей/неровностей на небольших поверхностях. Так обычно повышают детализацию объектов, без увеличения количества полигонов на объекте.

Вообще, возьмите за постулат, что в полигональных движках все состоит из плоских треугольников. Существуют, однако, и иные технологии, которыми можно визуализировать объемное тело, это raytracing (трассировака лучей: поверхности задаются параметрически в виде уравнений) и voxels (воксели: модели строятся из "объемных пикселей", это позволяет реализовать разрушение, разрезание моделей). Возможно вам будет интересно про них почитать.

Comment: Здесь стоит вопрос эффективности. Можно нарисовать цилиндр из полигонов или же утолстить один полигон и вырезать из него цилиндр discard’ом. Так и прощё, и быстрее. Особенно если речь идёт о весьма сложных объектах. Заявление “вообще, возьмите за постулат, что в полигональных движках все состоит из плоских треугольников” звучит излишне консервативно. Ведь никто же не мешает расширить существующую гибкость. 

Про воксели и raytracing  мне вероятно известно не менее, чем и вам. Был даже вопрос недавно по реализации трассировки лучей на GLSL, который так и остался без ответа.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее, как вы предлагаете утолстить полигон и вырезать из него цилиндр?

Comment: В этом и заключается весь вопрос.

Comment: Тогда откуда мнение что 
> Так и прощё, и быстрее

?

Comment: Из полигона можно вырезать относительно сложный объект, который не так просто создать обычным способом. Быстрее, чисто теоретически, потому что не нужно будет рисовать дополнительные полигоны для отображения простых геометрических объектов. Но всё в первую очередь зависит от реализации, и если она будет хромать на обе ноги, то все преимущества обратятся в одни недостатки.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется призмой. Строишь два параллельных многоугольника и соединяешь их боковыми гранями, представляющие собой прямоугольники. Только полигонов придётся больше рисовать в несколько раз.